# Django + Nginx on subdomain Bad request 400

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I need to deploy app to prod to subdomain. DNS A-record of app.mysite.com have value of machine. A-record of mysite.com have ip of different computer. Stack: Nginx, Django, Gunicorn.

Nginx works fine on IP, but invokes 400 on subdomain.

I've tried adding proxy_set_header values

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

but it doesn't help.

1. nginx/sites-enabled/mysite:
   (If I change server_name ti IP it wirks fine)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.mysite.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/mysite.sock;
    }
}
```

2. settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ip of machine,'127.0.0.1', 'app.mysite.com','mysite.com']
```

I want app to work only at subdomain. How could I achieve it?

Possibly helpful last Nginx process logs

```
Aug 10 21:23:59 my-machine systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 10 21:23:59 my-machine systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Aug 10 21:23:59 my-machine systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Aug 10 21:25:09 my-machine systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 10 21:25:09 my-machine systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: you'll need to find the actual source of the 400 error. If it's not in the nginx error log (check that you can see it in the nginx access log), then you should look at the gunicorn error log. If it's not there, then in your django logs. It's hard to debug errors without the actual error trace.

Comment: You should definitely check the nginx access log and see the 400 response there. If it's not there, then it means it's not even getting to nginx.

Comment: I don't think the nginx log you provided is the access log. Get the access log and the logs from gunicorn as well.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of testing and configuration the subdomain started after

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

in /etc/systemd/system

Answer (score 0):

I stopped all gunicorn workers with:

```
pkill gunicorn
```

and then restarted gunicorn, in my particular case is:

```
PYENV_VERSION=3.5.2 gunicorn -c gunicorn_cfg.py testing_webpage.wsgi --timeout 300 --workers=9 --bind=unix:/opt/peaku_co/run/gunicorn.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error too... Turns out I had turned on **Force HTTPS redirect** on my DNS provider and yet I was listening on port 80 on my VPS on HTTP without SSL certificate installed.
I fixed by **installing an SSL certificate on my VPS** and rebooting gunicorn.